# Why the SML function show me this "type mismatch" error?

Tags: types, sml

I tried to define a SML function which will zip two lists into one:

```
fun zip(vs:string list, ps:int list) : string*int list =
    case (vs,ps) of
       (v::vv,p::pp) => (v,p) :: zip(vv,pp)
     | _ => []
```

But it reports such error:

```
stdIn:3.20-3.39 Error: operator and operand don't agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: (string * int) * (string * int) list
  operand:         (string * int) * (string * int list)
  in expression:
    (v,p) :: zip (vv,pp)
```

I can't understand the error and can't find where is the mistake of my function.

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you meant this:

```
fun zip(vs:string list, ps:int list) : (string * int) list =
    case (vs,ps) of
       (v::vv,p::pp) => (v,p) :: zip(vv,pp)
     | _ => []
```

Notice that `(string * int) list` is not the same as `string * int list`. This latter would be interpreted as `string * (int list)` which is what the SML error message is saying.

As a matter of fact you can get rid of types whatsoever and it gets fixed thanks to type inference:

```
fun zip(vs, ps) =
    case (vs,ps) of
       (v::vv,p::pp) => (v,p) :: zip(vv,pp)
     | _ => []
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the following to be prettier, though mostly equivalent.

```
fun zip ([], []) = []
  | zip (v :: vs, p :: ps) = (v, p) :: zip(vv, pp)
```

The difference is that it will fail when the lists have unequal lengths.  You can handle this by failing, or returning the empty list when one of them are empty (as you're doing now.)

See `zip` and `zipEq` here http://www.standardml.org/Basis/list-pair.html